# Accessing controller properties within Ember Data REST Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to access a controller property to build custom URLs in my RESTAdapter instances, but I can't find a way to access the controller within the context of an adapter. Here's what I have:

I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend(
{
    first_name:     DS.attr('string'),
    last_name:      DS.attr('string'),
    date_of_birth:  DS.attr('string'),
    created_at:     DS.attr('string'),
    updated_at:     DS.attr('string')
});
```

The resource REST URL for this model looks something like this:
https://api.server.com/v1/accounts/**:account_id**/customers/**:customer_id**

I'm extending the RESTAdapter in Ember Data for most of my models so I can customize resource URLs individually. Like this:

```
App.CustomerAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
{
    buildURL: function(type, id)
    {
        // I need access to an account_id here:
        return "new_url";
    }
});
```

As you can see, in this example I need an account ID in the URL to be able to query a customer object. The account ID is something that the user would have had to supply by logging-in and is stored in an `AccountController` which is an instance of `Ember.Controller`.

My question is, how can I access a property from my `AccountController` within my `CustomerAdapter`? Here are the things I've tried, **none** have worked:

```
App.CustomerAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
{
    buildURL: function(type, id)
    {
        var account_id = this.controllerFor('account').get('activeAccount').get('id');
        return "new_url";
    }
});
```

,

```
App.CustomerAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
{
    needs:                ['account'],
    accountController:    Ember.computed.alias("controllers.account"),

    buildURL: function(type, id)
    {
        var account_id = this.get('accountController').get('activeAccount').get('id');
        return "new_url";
    }
});
```

,

```
App.CustomerAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
{
    activeAccountBinding = Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.AccountController.activeAccount');

    buildURL: function(type, id)
    {
        var account_id = this.get('activeAccount').get('id');
        return "new_url";
    }
});
```

At this point, the only hack I can think of, is to put the account ID in a global variable outside of Ember and access it from there within the Adapter.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem, and essentially we do a global variable, and feel guilty about it.  Ours is in Ember Model, but the same concept and problem exists.  Another solution is to use findQuery, but this returns a collection, so then you have to pull the item out of the collection.

```
App.CustomerAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
{
    buildURL: function(type, id)
    {
        var params = type.params;
        return "new_url" + params.account_id;
    }
});
```

In Some Route:

```
App.BlahRoute = Em.Route.extend({

   model: function(params){
      App.Customer.params = {account_id:123};
      this.get('store').find('customer', 3);
   }
});
```

Comment: Yea, I thought of something similar using metadata, but it's still a glorified global variable. I might need to get down and dirty with relationships. I see a **findHasMany** method in the RESTAdaptor which I still haven't figured out how to use...

Comment: It's an internal method :)

Comment: @Kingpin2k  It looks like a more straightforward way still isn't supported by Ember.js.  Do you agree?

Comment: No I don't agree ;) Ember Data and Ember.JS are two different products, Ember.JS works without Ember Data.  If you were to say a more straightforward way still isn't supported by Ember Data, then I'd definitely agree.

Comment: @Kingpin2k D'oh!  Thank you for the distinction.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can access controller's properties in context of another controller.

I see that you tried somewhat similar, but anyway maybe this would work for adapter:

```
App.YourController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['theOtherController'],
    someFunction: function () {
        var con = this.get('controllers.theOtherController');
        return con.get('propertyYouNeed');
    },
});
```

Also, have you thought about adding AccountId property to your Customer model?

Maybe automatic URL can be achieved with proper routing?

Comment: Yea accessing controllers from another controller works well, but that doesn't work for adapters :(

I can add accountId properties into the model but I can't see how exactly that helps because I can't really read model instances when I make the query to get all customers of an account.

What do you mean by proper routing?